# how to check if a field of a column is null or not , if NULL then update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

CREATE PROCEDURE:-I have a table named EVALUATOR with a column TAG. I need to find if the column TAG has NULL values or not. if it does then update it with values present in TAG table.

```
TAG tabel:
   Tag_id  tag_name   tag
    1        c++       cp
    2        oracle    orc
    3        java      jv
```

EVALUATOR table:

```
   eval_id   eval_name   domain     specialization   tag

     1        JOHN       DATABASE      oracle         NULL
     2        MATTHEW     PROGRAMMING    JAVA          jv
     3        EDWARD     PROGRAMMING    C++           NULL
```

Comment: Update with what values exactly?

Comment: Sample data and desired results are very helpful for explaining what you need to do.

Comment: `UPDATE e SET e.tag = t.tag FROM dbo.Evaluator AS e INNER JOIN dbo.Tag AS t ON t.tag_name = e.specialization WHERE t.tag IS NULL;`

Comment: However, why are you storing the tag name in both places? (That's redundant - you should only store the name of something once.) Why are the tags stored in the same table? Seems kind of limiting, what I want to tag John with both Oracle and Java?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you can update empty tag values like this

```
update evaluator
set tag = 'some_tag'
where tag is null
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some sort of "default" value in the `tag` table:

```
update evaluator
    set tag = (select t.tag from tag where isdefault = 1)
    where tag is null;
```

I suspect that you want something like this:

```
update evaluator e
    set tag = (select t.tag from tag t where e.specialization = t.tag_name)
    where e.tag is null;
```

Comment: I just added the table. if that could help

Answer (score 0):

> it depends how in which way you want to update the records.

if you want to update it manually then use:

```
update EVALUATOR 
set tag = 'my_common_tag_to_all_null_values'
where tag is null
```

or
if you want to update using join then use:
[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/87a615/15)

```
create table TAG(
tag_id int identity(1,1),
  tag_name varchar(50),
  tag varchar(50)
)
insert into TAG (tag_name,tag) values('c++','cp'),
('oracle','orc'),('java','jv')

create table EVALUATOR(
eval_id int identity(1,1),
  eval_name varchar(50),
  domain varchar(50),
    specialization varchar(50),
  tag varchar(50)
)
```

Query:

```
update ed
set ed.tag=tg.tag
from EVALUATOR ed join TAG tg on tg.tag_name=ed.specialization where 
ed.tag is null


select * from EVALUATOR
```